# How to make my pyspark code for sieve of eratosthenes scalable for large range of numbers?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am trying to write a pyspark script to generate all the prime numbers <= a given number. For example, generate all the primes upto 1 billion.

I wrote the following code. It does well for small numbers, but as soon as the number goes to 100 million, the script performs poorly.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from math import isqrt

def is_perfect_square(num):
  root = isqrt(num)
  return root*root == num


def sieve_of_eratosthenes_partition(iterator):
    upper_limit = max(iterator) # Upper limit for prime number generation
    prime_flag = [True] * len(iterator) # Initialize boolean array for primes
    result = []
    cur_prime = 2

    while cur_prime * cur_prime <= upper_limit:
        i = 0
        if ((cur_prime % 2 == 0 and cur_prime != 2) or is_perfect_square(cur_prime)):
          cur_prime += 1
        else:
          for num in iterator:
            if(num % cur_prime == 0 and num != cur_prime):
              prime_flag[i] = False
            i += 1  
          cur_prime += 1

    for num, is_prime in zip(iterator, prime_flag):
        if is_prime and num > 1:
            result.append(num)
    return result

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SievePrimesMapPartitions").getOrCreate()
n = 10**7 # End range 

numbers = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1, n+1), 1000)
result_rdd = numbers.mapPartitions(sieve_of_eratosthenes_partition)

# result_rdd.map(str).saveAsTextFile("primes")

primes = result_rdd.collect()
print(primes)
print(len(primes))
```

I am dividing my range (1, 10 million) into 1000 partitions like (1.....10,000), (10,0001....20,000) and so on. For each partition, I am applying the sieve function. The sieve iteratively filters out all the multiples of primes in the given range.

I can see the limiting factor in my script. For partition with the range of smallest numbers, say (1...10,000), the sieve function will iterate upto 100 only.
However, for the partition with the range of largest numbers, i.e., the last partition (9,990,000....10,000,000), the sieve function will iterate upto sqrt(10 million). In effect, the performance of my script is decided by the time taken to process the partition with the largest numbers.

How can I improve upon this? Is there any other way to partition my dataset?
One other thought that came to my mind is to make a sieve upto sqrt(given number). Then distribute this sieve to the nodes. On each node, filter out all the multiples of the respective sieves and combine the results to get the list of primes. Does this look like an improvement?

Comment: How long does it take to find all primes in the range (1, 10 million)?

Comment: I ran the code on free version of google colab with 2 cores. The time taken was like this:
1 to 1,000   3s
1 to 10,000   3s  
1 to 100,000  4s
1 to 1,000,000  1m4s  

1 to 10,000,000 1m27s

1 to 100,000,000  34m37s

Comment: Hm, naive  implementation takes 2s for for range 10m and 23s for range 100m on Apple M2 processor.

Answer (score 1):

Like you thought, a good way of scaling up a Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm can be doneby initially creating a smaller sieve up to the square root of the given number and then distributing this sieve across your cluster.

Here's how you could implement this:

```py
    def soe_sqrt(n):
        limit = isqrt(n)
        prime_flag = [True] * (limit + 1)
        primes = []
        for p in range(2, limit + 1):
            if prime_flag[p]:
                primes.append(p)
                for i in range(p * p, limit + 1, p):
                    prime_flag[i] = False
        return primes
```

then you broadcast it to your sparks:

```py
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SievePrimesMapPartitions").getOrCreate()
    n = 10**9  # 1 billion
    primes_upto_sqrt_n = soe_sqrt(n)
    primes_broadcast = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(primes_upto_sqrt_n)
```

now you just get your cluster to use the broadcasted list of primes to filter out their multiples.

```py
    def soe_partition(primes_broadcast):
        def filter_primes(iterator):
            primes = primes_broadcast.value
            numbers = set(iterator)
            for prime in primes:
                multiples = {prime * i for i in range(2, (max(numbers) // prime) + 1)}
                numbers -= multiples
            return list(numbers)

        return filter_primes


    numbers = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(2, n + 1), 1000)
    result_rdd = numbers.mapPartitions(soe_partition(primes_broadcast))
```

now you just have to print your results like you've done, and boom. a bajillion primes are at your fingertips :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I meant was to partition my primes list and broadcast a sublist of numbers iteratively. Each node will have a sublist of sieve and every node has the same sublist of numbers. Apply respective sieves and then combine the result

Comment: @Lemon hmm, that method would definitely be better for memory usage, and seeing how you are using google colab, it may be the better approach for you. Though, since it's iterative, your total runtime will increase due to the overhead from multiple broadcasts and subsequent processing of chunks. I can try adding an edit with that approach if you want me to.

Comment: Yeah, broadcasting the list iteratively will definitely increase overhead costs. 
I ran your code on google colab for 1 million. It took 5m6s